# Rails 3 - include value in query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, model, include

I am a bit confused, how works **include**.

I have this query to database: **@car = Car.includes(:colors).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])**
In table **Car** I have columns: name, price, color, ...
In table **Colors** columns: car_id, name, color_name, ...

In my view I can use for printing price of the car **@car.price**, but I can't use **@car.color_name**, why?

And the another problem - I have in both tables the column called **have**, how I will to know, with which one I am working currently? If I will do **@car.name**, so this value will be take from **Cars** table or **Colors**?

I am sorry for maybe stupid question, but I don't know, how to work with the data from 2 tables.

Comment: Add models code to the question. It seems a simple problem but I need more information to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is a Car `has_many` Colors association it will look something like this:

```
# This loads 10 cars with offset X
@cars = Car.includes(:colors).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
# the first car found
@car = @cars.first
# Name of the Car
@car.name
# All colors of the car
@car.colors
# The name of the first color
@car.colors.first.name
```

When you use the `includes` statement, this does not mean both models are mixed into each other. The associations are just preloaded, but the common rails association structure is still the same... Hope this helps :)